# How do I add a custom product attribute next to the price on the front-end?

Tags: product, magento-1.9, product-list, products-view

I have ~24.000 products, each of them have a custom product attribute called `item_size`.

How do I make sure the `item_size` attribute show's up on every page where products are shown? When you search for products or view all products in a certain category for example.

Here's an example:

[image]

The product on the left is what I would like it to look like. The product on the right is what it currently looks like. I'm using the default Magento 1.9 theme.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1:** To access the Product Attribute you can use below code.

```
$_product->getData('attributeCode');
```

Please note that the `product` has to be lowercase.

**Step 2:** This is Listing page so. you have theme folder `template/catalog/product/list.phtml file`.

**Step 3:** search below code.

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```

**Step 4:** create `span` tag near and give class and based on that set the CSS.

Note: If you can display data on site and share the link then I can help to what exactly CSS used/

Let me know if any comments.

Comment: Using `<?php echo $_Product->getData('item_size'); ?>` doesn't work. It deletes all product from the page, except the first one. Any ideas?

Comment: @narzero try `$_product->...` (lowercase)

Comment: U welcome..... 

Comment: @KeyulShah How do I wrap the `item_size` attribute inside a `<span>` or `<div>`? It's inserted as plain text right now..

Comment: I think It will show correctly becasue if your product has special price then structure change so

Comment: Put get data code in 'div' tsg simple